# All https sites have expired certificates

Tags: https

Suddenly all https sites have expired certificates on all browsers, even formatting and reinstalling Windows didn't work! I tried many different connections as well.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Have you checked that the clock in your computer is set to the right date?

Also, what sites?  Maybe they actually are expired...

Comment: +1 for a suggestion I will file for future reference!

Comment: +1 - 9.5 out of 10 cases this happens is indeed due to a wrongly set system clock.

Comment: Poor guy reinstalled Windows!

Comment: Could be due to a dead CMOS battery

Comment: How convenient.  Right after daylight savings time.....

Comment: @John daylight savings isn't applicable to all areas

Comment: @Sathya: True, just a theory.